# What is $df^{-1}(f(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\end{smallmatrix}))$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> $$f:\mathbb{R}\times[0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}^2,f\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^x \cos y \\e^x \sin y\end{pmatrix}$$

which is $\exp(z)$

I know that $df(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}e^x\cos y && -e^x\sin y\\e^x\sin y&&e^x\cos y\end{pmatrix}$.

How can I determine $df^{-1}\Bigg(f\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\end{pmatrix}\Bigg)$?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We look for posts that have more than just a problem - please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more info. The information that is missing here includes the source and motivation of the question, along with any attempts you have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $df^{-1}\Bigg(f\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\end{pmatrix}\Bigg)=(df(x,y))^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}e^x\cos y && -e^x\sin y\\e^x\sin y&&e^x\cos y\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$.

Comment: Why the downvote ????????